# form.is_valid() not working when using django forms for updating information to the databse

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I wanna be able to update information of a router in the database using a form, I wanna have a form pre-populated with that specific router details. The problem is that form.is_valid() is not working

I tried using {{ form.errors }} {{ form.non_field_errors }} and print(form.errors) but none of them worked

views.py (incomplete)

```
def info_router(request, pk):
    rout = Routers.objects.get(sn=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':  # Insert the info in forms
        form = UpdateRouter()
        rout = Routers.objects.get(sn=pk)
        args = {'router': rout}
        return render(request, "router_info.html", args)

    if request.POST.get('delete'):
        # Delete router

        rout.delete()
        messages.warning(request, 'Router was deleted from the database!')
        return redirect("db_router")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Updating the form
        form = UpdateRouter(instance=Routers.objects.get(sn=pk))
        print(form)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = UpdateRouter.cleaned_data
            mac = data['mac']

            print(mac)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('db_router')
        else:
            print("Invalid form")

    return render(request, "db_router.html", {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateRouter(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Routers
        fields = ['model', 'ip_addr', 'name', 'sn', 'mac']
```

template

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group"> <!-- Form with the router details -->
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Serial number:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" name="sn" value="{{ router.sn }}" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Model:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" value="{{ router.model }}" name="model" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Ip address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" value="{{ router.ip_addr }}" name="ip_addr">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" value="{{ router.name }}" name="name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Mac address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" value="{{ router.mac }}" name="mac">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Extra info:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="extra_info" id="FormControlTextarea" rows="3">Example of some info</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> <!-- Responsible for updating the router -->
        <a href="{% url "db_router" %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float: right"> <!-- Responsible for the delete modal to open -->
            Delete
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never passed `request.POST` and `rquest.FILES`. If you want to update the fields and files, you need to `form.save()` your form:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #Updating the form
    form = UpdateRouter(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=Routers.objects.get(sn=pk))
    print(form)
    print(form.errors)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        mac = data['mac']
        form.save()
        print(mac)
        return redirect('db_router')
    else:
        print("Invalid form")
```

If you do not pass `request.POST` and/or `request.FILES`, then Django does not consider the form filled in, and it is never considered valid.

If you pass both files and data, then you need to add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    <!-- -->
</form>
```

Comment: I applied the changes you said, form.is_valid() is now True but now I'm getting this
" type object 'UpdateRouter' has no attribute 'cleaned_data'"

Comment: @JoãoDias: yes, that should be `form.cleaned_data` :)

Comment: So I was getting an error here ```rout = Routers.objects.get(sn=pk) ```so I changed it to ``` rout = get_object_or_404(Routers, sn=pk) ``` so even though the details are being updated (thank you) I still get an error

Comment: *When I click the update button*
"Not Found: /router_info/db_router" "No Routers matches the given query."

the url stays like this "router_info/db_router" and it should be just db_router, this is probably something simple, I'm a begginer to Django so can't figure it out xd

Comment: @JoãoDias: You need to `redirect`, not `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Comment: Oh yeaaa! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a bound_form

```
form = UpdateRouter(request.POST)
```

form = UpdateRouter(request.POST) binds the data to the form class. then validate 
the inputs using is_valid().